# How to indicate a Cell in a DBGrid?

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-7, dbgrid

I want to get data out of a specific cell in a DBGrid ? How can I do this in Delphi 7 ? I know with a Stringgrid it was easy you only used `StringGrid1.Cells[2,1]` if you wanted to show to row 2 column 1, but is there any way to accomplish this with a DBGrid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TDBGrid` doesn't contain any data; that comes from the connected `TDataSet`. So to retrieve information, you read the database itself. The current row in the `DBGrid` is the current record (row) in the `DataSet`, and the column is the `TField` connected to the column in that row.

So if you want to read from the third column in the grid, and that column is attached to a field named 'Customer' in the dataset, you'd just read that field:

```
Customer := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('Customer').AsString;
```

Or, of course better (since you should have access to the dataset directly in your code):

```
Customer := CustomerTable.FieldByName('Customer').AsString;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what your comment means. I've explained exactly how to get the data.

Comment: With the method you gave me I can still not get to the second row of the `DBGrid`? I can get all the values of the first row. But is their a way to get the data from the second row ext?

Comment: Yes. Move the record pointer to the next row using `DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Next;` or `CustomerTable.Next;`. The grid has no data (as I said in my first sentence) - you **must** read it from the table itself.